# WebView Application stopped by clicking back button

Tags: android, webview

i have created a WebView for a Website. I used this Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.loadUrl("http://www.ab-parfume.de/");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    };
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
      if(webView.canGoBack()){
       webView.goBack();
                return true;
      }
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
}
```

So my Problem is if i click on the Back Button the Application stopped

Comment: what do you wanna do when the back key is pressed ?

Comment: If i click on the back button it should be go back to the previous Site in the webview

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in method for this, because your solution never worked.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(/*Check for a previous website*/)
        {
            //Put the code for previous website in here
        }
        else
        {
            //Put the code for finishing this Activity, or what else you want
        }
    }
```